# Python open file and get eveyrthing before second space

Tags: python, file, strip, readlines

I have this in my file:
*2023-09-08 10:40:04 twitter 

2023-09-08 10:40:05 sreality*
I need to get first and second text from the last line.
I tried this but it get only text before first space:

```
with open("mujlist.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

if not lines:
    print("There is nothing in your file")
else: 
    last_line = lines[-1].split(' ', 2)[0].strip()  

    print(last_line)
```

Do you have some idea what to change to get:
*2023-09-08 10:40:05* ?

Thank you

Comment: @Mirek what is this? if it's relevant information for the question, edit the question and post it there, not in a comment. For what I see, your file don't contain text1 text2 text3. You must post in your question a reproducible example, it you put generic texts you will get answers for what you ask, which might not work at all for your actual data.

Comment: Ok, your code is running and is it possible to get in this form?  2023-09-08 10:40:05

Comment: ok, your file is this. when executing my code you should get ["2023-09-08", 
 "10:40:05"]  which is what you are asking. Do you want this merged as a string? Then use .join: to join the elements of the list `last_line=' '.join(lines[-1].split(' ')[:2])`

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get *first* and *second* text from the **last line**..

If your *text-file* is relatively large, you might want to consider reading it from the end :

```
with open("mujlist.txt", "rb") as f:
    f.seek(-1, 2) # go the end of file

    while f.read(1) != b"\n":
        f.seek(-2, 1) # step back twice from current position

    first, second, *_ = f.readline().decode().split() # change the sep if needed
```

Output :

```
print(first, second)
# 2023-09-08 10:40:05

print(" ".join([first, second]))
# 2023-09-08 10:40:05
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file. Read all lines. Locate last line. Locate first 2 tokens. Print them out.

```
with open('mujlist.txt') as file:
    print(*file.readlines()[-1].split()[:2])
```

**Output:**

```
2023-09-08 10:40:05
```

**Note:**

If the file doesn't contain at least one line, this will fail